# Return the maximum value of two columns in a dataframe (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I currently have a dataframe and would like to return the minimum value of two columns (eg. X and Y).

I have tried:

```
print(df.loc[:, ['X', 'Y']].min())
```

However, it prints out:

```
Control NSAF   -9.851210
Wild NSAF      -9.730507
dtype: float64
```

Whereas I just want -9.851210. Is there a way to just get the single minimum number?

Thank you

Comment: Read the docs https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.min.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add one more `min`

```
print(df.loc[:, ['X', 'Y']].min().min())
```

Answer (score 4):

The below given example may be useful for you to find

> maximum and minimum of "X" and "Y" columns

```
  df[["X", "Y"]].max(axis=1)
  df[["X", "Y"]].min(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 3):

use the numpy `min` method on the underlying `values` attribute

```
df.loc[:, ['X', 'Y']].values.min()
```

You can even find the locations of `'X'` and `'Y'` ahead of time

```
j = [df.columns.get_loc(c) for c in ['X', 'Y']]
df.values[:, j].min()
```